# When managing GCP firewall policies / rules using terraform - how to know what the ID is?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-networking

I've been referring to this guide: https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/hierarchical-firewall-policy-automation-terraform and, unless I'm reading wrong, it seems to start with the assumption I have a folder setup already.

What I've tried so far is:

- Creating a firewall policy manually via the GCP web console (ie - with a mouse etc)
- Creating a resource block in terraform
- Running terraform import

The resource block:

```
resource "google_compute_firewall_policy" "fw-policy-name" {
}
```

The terraform command:

```
terraform import google_compute_firewall_policy.fw-policy-name fw-policy-name
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
Error: Error when reading or editing ComputeFirewallPolicy "locations/global/firewallPolicies/fw-policy-name": googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'firewallPolicy': 'firewallPolicies/fw-policy-name'. Must be a match of regex '(firewallPolicies/)?[0-9]{0,20}', invalid
```

I think (though I'm not sure) that this is suggesting that I use the following for the import command:

```
terraform import google_compute_firewall_policy.fw-policy-name <FOLDER ID INTEGER>
```

Is that correct?

I don't know how to either create a new folder, or to check which folder the firewall policy I've created sits within.

Context is I want to have network / firewall settings for compute instance managed via terraform.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this

Comment: @Rob It's about capturing that with terraform though - there are a lot of similar questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terraform - are they all "on-topic"?

Comment: Opinions vary and I understand Rob's view also. I consider Terraform on-topic. It is both a programming script/language and a tool that programmers use. Because of how large the software engineering world is, there will be different opinions on almost everything.

Comment: @JohnHanley Makes sense - following robs comment I realised there was a DevOps stack exchange, perhaps I could have posted there... though looking through the current SO terraform posts what I've done doesn't seem to be that different, so who knows :)

Answer (score 1):

The document you reference is talking about setting firewall policies that would apply across a complex multi-project organisation. If you are just wanting to control firewall settings for compute instances, then I'd recommend using network-tags.

When creating instances using the `google_compute_instance` resource type, you would specify one or more network tags using the `tags` argument, for example `web-server`:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
  name         = "my-instance"
  machine_type = "n2-standard-2"
  zone         = "us-central1-a"

  tags = ["web-server"]

  ...
```

You then specify firewall rules using the `google_compute_firewall` resource:

```
resource "google_compute_firewall" "rules" {
  project     = "my-project-name"
  name        = "my-firewall-rule"
  network     = "default"
  description = "Creates firewall rule targeting tagged instances"

  allow {
    protocol  = "tcp"
    ports     = ["80", "443",]
  }

  target_tags = ["web-server"]
}
```

Comment: I think this makes more sense for my actual usage ( i haven't set up an organisation ) though the code needs to use source / target tags i think ?

Comment: Source tags may also make sense - it would depend on your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

This error is expected as you need to specify the firewall policy ID not the name, that is why the `400: Invalid value for field`.

To get the IDs you can run below commands

```
  $ gcloud compute firewall-policies  list --organization=123456789123
    ID: 987654321012
    DISPLAY_NAME: orgpolicytest
    DESCRIPTION:
```

Then to get the selfLink run the below command.

```
  $ gcloud compute firewall-policies  describe orgpolicytest --organization=123456789123 --format 'value(selfLink)'
    https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/locations/global/firewallPolicies/987654321012
```

And finally to import by running the below command with the Id which is considered the name (I know this is an issue in the documentation, I will need to report this).

```
$ terraform import google_compute_firewall_policy.default locations/global/firewallPolicies/{{name}}
$ terraform import google_compute_firewall_policy.default locations/global/firewallPolicies/987654321012
Or
$ terraform import google_compute_firewall_policy.default {{name}}
$ terraform import google_compute_firewall_policy.default 987654321012
```

Comment: Ah - I'm just running this as a GCP Project under my personal account, so perhaps this doesn't apply to me

Comment: No problem please refer to the documentation [1].
```
Hierarchical firewall policy rules let you create and enforce a consistent firewall policy across your organization. Rules can explicitly allow or deny connections or delegate evaluation to lower level policies. Policies can be created within organizations or folders.
```
[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_firewall_policy

Comment: Thanks - I only realised during this that organization != project, and 'folders' are something I'm yet to figure :)